# C++: Grouping math functions and their derivatives into a single entity

Tags: c++

I would like to implement various mathematical functions such as Sigmoid (Logistic), ReLU, etc. Along with each of these, I would like to implement their derivatives.

Given that these math functions are all very simple one-liners, I would like to make them inline. In addition, I would like to be able to organize the functions into single entities by name and be able to call the regular activation or derivative function like so:

```
Sigmoid.Activate(0.5)
Sigmoid.Derivate(0.5)
```

Lastly, I would like to be able to store these as a field of an object, so if I were to incorporate a Neuron for a neural network, I would be able to have a field called `activation` and be able to call it like so:

```
this->activation.Derivate(this->input);
```

I am conflicted when it comes to finding an appropriate way to accomplish this. I have read that, in general, static inline functions are a code smell. However, creating a separate instance for every single object that makes use of the functions seems redundant and a waste of memory. In fact, having any instance at all seems wasteful, since I essentially just want to group two functions into one name. I have considered using a namespace for each function, but then I wouldn't be able to specify which function an object should use.

Static classes seems to be the only valid solution. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: The first criteria could be satisfied by keeping the functions in a namespace called `Sigmoid`: they'd then be "organised by name". If `Derivate` in your second example depends on the state of `this->activation`, then it's a completely different function and should be a method.

Comment: What about **static members** of each class?

Comment: your sigmoid should be part of your neuron just like it's derivative.  that way if, say, you didn't want to use tanh(x) with its derivative of 1 - (tan(x) * tan(x)) you still have that single locality of where to change it. alternatively you can make it customizable with std::function. Code smell is a term used by style entheausiests at the least. the features of the language are there for a reason. There IS a proper use for them.

Comment: You could have one object for each function, all these objects inhereting from an abstract class, each neuron having a pointer to one such object.

Comment: As there can be functions, which have parameters, a field is not a bad option. Yes, even if the object has no members, then it will take some space (typically one byte). I wouldn't worry about it. Note, that in C++20, we will (hopefully) have [no_unique_address](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.attr.nouniqueaddr).

Comment: If you want to assign a "function pair" to a Neuron at *runtime* you need to have at least one instance of an object, I can't see any way around that.

Comment: what are your reasons for inlining them though? It shouldn't really be based on how many lines there are in a function since inlining in c++ pretty much only affects linkage now.

Answer (score 2):

This might not match all of your criteria, however, I think it's useful. Classes aren't the solution to everything, so why not have the class's `activation` field be a function pointer type that returns a (value, derivative) pair:

```
// Example library
using value_derivative = std::pair<double,double>;
enum ReturnType {
    VALUE,
    DERIVATIVE
};
using ActivationFunction = std::function<value_derivative(double)>;

value_derivative sigmoid(double z) {
    double ez = exp(-z);
    double val = 1.0/(1+ez);
    return std::make_pair(val, val*(1.0-val));
}

// Example usage
ActivationFunction activation = sigmoid;
auto act = activation(1);
double value = std::get<VALUE>(act);
double derivative = std::get<DERIVATIVE>(act);
std::tie(value,derivative) = activation(2);
```

Note that an ancillary benefit of this is that when the activation function has a nice differential equation, the derivative is often simpler to calculate using intermediate terms in the computation of the value.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to be able to assign a choice of a pair of functions to a field of a `Neuron` at *runtime* then you will need at least one instance of a polymorphic object. [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) is quite convenient for this but you could achieve something similar with an abstract base class. You could combine two `std::function` using a simple struct.

```
struct Activation {
    std::function<double(double)> activate;
    std::function<double(double)> derivative;
};
```

Then you can have a single instance of this struct for sigmoid:

```
const Activation& sigmoid() {
    static const Activation activation {
        [](double z){ return 1.0/(1.0+exp(-z)); },
        [](double z){ auto a=exp(z); auto b=1.0+a; return a/(b*b);  }
    };
    return activation;
}
```

Then you can store a reference to this instance in a field of Neuron:

```
class Neuron {
    const Activation& activation;
  public:
    Neuron(const Activation& activation) : activation(activation) {}
    void doSomething() {
        std::cout << activation.derivative(0.5) << "\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    Neuron n(sigmoid());
    n.doSomething();
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BfyXbirjlBc0vy3T).

Comment: Why not having an object sigmoid inheriting from a pure virtual class Activation? And  Neuron having a pointer  Activation* ?

Comment: @Damien, As I said, you could use an abstract base class but I don't think it is clearer. `std::function` is designed to be a polymophic wrapper for function objects so it is quite convenient for this kind of thing. But I encourage you to add your own answer using an `Activation` abstract base class as an alternative.

Comment: @Damien Also, a pure virtual class `Activation` could add more complexity in terms of ownership. E.g say you wanted to have an `ActivationFactory`. Using a simple struct containing two `std::function` you can just return the struct by-value and `std::function` handles the ownership. With a virtual class `Activation` you would have to return a `std::unique_ptr<Activation>` then store that somewhere and use `.get()` to get a non-owning raw-pointer to pass to Neuron.

Comment: Thank you for these clear explanations. I did not have such a Factory in mind

Answer (score 0):

The storage of these functions as objects can be achieved with functors. These are classes with their () operator overloaded, so that you can call the class like a function:

```
class my_functor {
    return_type operator() (param_type param) { /* .. */ }
}
```

An advantage of this is that you can also store a state inside the class. You can call this as:

```
std::cout << this->instance_of_my_functor(42);
```

Functors have their advantages over function pointers due to their ability to store a state, which you might find beneficial. It is also possible to use inheritance with them, override the operator(s) as you see fit.